# Azure DevOps Template - conditions

Tags: templates, azure-devops, conditional-statements

Is it possible to add some conditions to this way of using templates?

I would like to use conditions based on branches.

If branch = main or development > deploy to dev

Only if branch > main, deploy to staging

The complete Pipeline:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main

pool: 'On-Prem Pool'

variables:
  - group: ContainerRegistry
  - group:xyz
  - name: appName
    value: 'xyz'
  - name: dockerfilePath
    value: '**/Dockerfile'


stages:


# Build App and push to container registry

- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push to container registry
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build job
    pool: 'On-Prem Pool'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Login to ACR
      inputs:
        command: login
        containerRegistry: $(registryServiceConnection)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build container image
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: $(appName)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(registryServiceConnection)
        tags: $(Build.BuildId)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push container image
      inputs:
        command: push
        repository: $(appName)
        containerRegistry: $(registryServiceConnection)
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')) # Don´t push to ACR on Pull Requests




# Infrastructure

# Lint the Bicep file.
- stage: Lint
  jobs: 
  - template: pipeline-templates/lint.yml

 # Deploy to the dev environment.
- template: pipeline-templates/deploy.yml
  parameters:
    environmentType: Development
    resourceGroupName: rg-xx
    appSuffix: xyz
    costCenter: 'xyz'
    serviceConnectionName: 'SVCxx'
    dockerRegistryPassword: $(dockerRegistryPassword)
    dockerRegistryUserName: $(dockerRegistryUserName)
    containerTag: $(Build.BuildId)
    registryUrl: $(registryUrl)
    cpuCores: 0.5 
    memory: 1
    minReplicas: 0
    maxReplicas: 1



 # Deploy to the staging environment.
- template: pipeline-templates/deploy.yml
  parameters:
    environmentType: Staging
    resourceGroupName: rg-xxx-001
    appSuffix: xyz
    costCenter: 'xyz'
    serviceConnectionName: 'SVCxxx'
    dockerRegistryPassword: $(dockerRegistryPassword)
    dockerRegistryUserName: $(dockerRegistryUserName)
    containerTag: $(Build.BuildId)
    registryUrl: $(registryUrl)
    cpuCores: 0.5 
    memory: 1 
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 2
)
```

And it is the last two -templates I would like to apply some conditions on.

Many thanks!

Comment: this doesnt make sense. if main or development deploy to dev, if main deploy to stage?

Comment: Hi , any update? did my post help?

Comment: I see this sounds strange in regards of the branches, however the main point was how to handle the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved it in a similar way;

```
- stage: BuildDeployProd
  displayName: Build and deploy Prod env
  jobs:
  - template: pipeline-templates/deploy.yml
      parameters:
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
```

Comment: you could mark your post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

During my test, I edited my `build.yaml` as below. And when I ran it, the second template could evaluate correctly but the third one not, and thus, the third template was skipped.
[image]

```
pool: 
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    env: dev

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.QueuedBy'], 'Ceeno') }}:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      env: qa

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.QueuedBy'], 'Vacee') }}:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      env: prod
```

And if you are looking for the evaluation for other method or other scenario, you could share with me for further investigations.